# React: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to fix this lint error at line `const def = (props) => {` in following sample code.

```
const propTypes = {
prop1: PropTypes.string,
prop2: PropTypes.string,
prop3: PropTypes.string,
prop4: PropTypes.string,
prop5: PropTypes.string,
}

const abc = (props) => {
some code here }

const def = (props) => {
<div>
<div className=" ..some classes..">{abc}</div>
<div className=" ..some classes..">{t('translation/something')}</div>

<div ...>
  <someComponent 
    do something
  />

if (some condition) {
do this
} else {
do that
}

</div>

};
```

Any idea why i am getting this lint error?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line.  It's the line after where you've got HTML instead of JS.

Comment: You can't have and `if` inside jsx. You need to use the `condition ? if true : if false` syntax.

Comment: i get the same lint error even if i just do `const def = (props) => {
<div> </div> };`

Comment: Duplicate of [List elements not rendering in React](/q/40324352/4642212) and [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](/q/28889450/4642212).

Answer (score 94):

You are not returning anything, at least from your snippet and comment.

`const def = (props) => { <div></div> };`

This is not returning anything, you are wrapping the body of the arrow function with curly braces but there is no return value.

`const def = (props) => { return (<div></div>); };` OR
`const def = (props) => <div></div>;`

These two solutions on the other hand are returning a valid React component. Keep also in mind that inside your `jsx` (as mentioned by @Adam) you can't have `if ... else ...` but only ternary operators.

Comment: Thanks. if i do `onst def = (props) => <div></div>;` i get error `Unexpected parentheses around single function argument having a body with no curly braces` and if i do `const def = (props) => { return (<div></div>); };` i get error `Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body `

Comment: Then just try `const def = props => (<div></div>);`

Comment: Thanks again. with that it wont show the error but i am getting `PropName is missing in props validation` for all the pros inside it. any idea why?

Comment: Yes you need to add every prop you use in the component inside the prop validation. You might want to check out the docs, you seem to be missing many key basics of React. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: adding `return` to `<Redirect to='/home'>` solved my issue

Answer (score 25):

Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

I had this similar error with this code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    players: state
}
```

To correct all I needed to do was add parenthesis around the curved brackets

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    players: state
});
```

Comment: What is the reason to do so?

Comment: I faced the same situation. I can't explain why it does work if you add the parentheses, tho.

Comment: You saved my time, @Steven. Thanks!

Comment: @NisanAbeywickrama ,  parentheses are used to return object, instead of doing :

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { players: state }
};

Comment: Even I want to know why this parenthesis bcz the fat arrow function should be  ()=>{ multi line expression } not ()=({ multi line expression })

Answer (score 10):

The return statements should place in one line.
Or
 the other option is to remove the curly brackets that bound the HTML statement.

example:

```
return posts.map((post, index) =>
    <div key={index}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: this worked for me. I got the same message because I had a .map and I was using {} instead of () to return the component/jsx 

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about solutions but a **temporary** workaround is to ask eslint to ignore it by adding the following on top of the problem line.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible way is (sure you can change array declaration to getting from db or another external resource):

```
const MyPosts = () => {

  let postsRawData = [
    { id: 1, text: 'Post 1', likesCount: '1' },
    { id: 2, text: 'Post 2', likesCount: '231' },
    { id: 3, text: 'Post 3', likesCount: '547' }
  ];

  const postsItems = []
  for (const [key, value] of postsRawData.entries()) {
    postsItems.push(<Post text={value.text} likesCount={value.likesCount} />)
  }

  return (
      <div className={css.posts}>Posts:
          {postsItems}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use a function component:

```
const def = (props) => {
<div>
<div className=" ..some classes..">{abc}</div>
<div className=" ..some classes..">{t('translation/something')}</div>

<div ...>
<someComponent 
 do something
/>

if (some condition) {
do this
} else {
do that
}

 </div>

};
```

In the function component, you have to write a return or just add parentheses. After the added return or parentheses your code should look like this:

```
const def = (props) => ({
<div>
<div className=" ..some classes..">{abc}</div>
<div className=" ..some classes..">{t('translation/something')}</div>

<div ...>
<someComponent 
 do something
/>

if (some condition) {
do this
} else {
do that
}

 </div>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the `eslint` error was caused by an unexpected use case. **Hence the code was correct, but `eslint` failed**:

```js
cy.customCommand().then(obj => {
      expect(obj.booleanProp).to.be.true;
    });
```

**`eslint` finds an expression which is generated, but not used.** That the generation produces a result (potential exception) is beyond the analyzer.

In defense of `eslint`: I don't expect the analyzer to anticipate this [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). And it's foremost usecase (prevent you from unfinished code-lines) is important. **So nobody to blame..**

I'd suggest to just **disable the warning linewise** like this:

```js
cy.customCommand().then(obj => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
      expect(obj.booleanProp).to.be.true;
    });
```

Comment: This was exactly my case and I was getting really frustrated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This Error Happens If you Don't add **return** before statement.

In my case I was Using

**str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);**

which is Incorrect. We have to Add return before this statement.

Like This

**return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);**

Hope this will Help You.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwIm9.png)

I got this error once when I have not returned the value when I was using useSelector.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the line with **default** instructions in switch block:

```
  handlePageChange = ({ btnType}) => {
    let { page } = this.state;
    switch (btnType) {
      case 'next':
        this.updatePage(page + 1);
        break;
      case 'prev':
        this.updatePage(page - 1);
        break;
      default: null;
    } 
  }
```

Instead of

```
default: null;
```

The line

```
default: ;
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The fault is within your if statement. Had same error some time ago. I got to noticed that Within my ternary operator, I was having lines of code sepereted from each other by commas, changed to using if statement still was having same error.

I corrected it by sepereting the expressions and giving each a seperate if statement (works with ternary operator too) but in the end, I was having too many redundant codes...annoying. Have not found any solution since then

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must have at least one "return" before your parent div tag in your function as follows

```js
const def = (props) => {    
   return(
       <div>
        [some other child div/codes here]    
       </div>
   )
};
```

Or, you can use an Arrow function in a single line as:

```js
const def = (props) => `<div> [some other child div/codes here] </div>`
```

In this case `"return"` is not compulsory.

Secondly, you should use "Conditional (ternary) Operator".

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to fix this error.

1. If you want to use curly braces then you have to use the return keyword sample below-

   <button onClick={() => setCount( (prevCount) => { return prevCount + 1})}>+

**OR**

2. Withour curly bracess you don't need to use return keyword

   <button onClick={() => setCount( (prevCount) => prevCount -1 )}>-

Answer (score -1):

Mostly this error occurs because we don't 'return' correctly. The most common solution to it is to put a pair of parenthesis () around your function's curly braces {}.

**The following code will produce error. See there is no return.**

```
const MyComponent= (state) => {
    anything: state;
}
```

**This is how you should write it correctly so that you don't see an error.**

```
const MyComponent= (state) => ({
    anything: state
});
```