# How to link to a show view from an index using react hooks with firestore data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out how to define a link to reference that can use a firebase document id to link to a show view for that document. I can render an index. I cannot find a way to define a link to the document.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/vetswhocode/build-a-crud-firestore-app-in-react-gatsby-with-hooks-4ig9) - which is good to get the CRUD steps other than the show view. I can find other [tutorials](https://www.djamware.com/post/5bc50ea680aca7466989441d/reactjs-firebase-tutorial-building-firestore-crud-web-application) that do this with class components and the closest I've been able to find using hooks is this incomplete [project repo](https://github.com/fazanata/react-firebase).

I want to try and add a link in the index to show the document in a new view.

I have an index with:

```
  const useBlogs = () => {
const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]); //useState() hook, sets initial state to an empty array
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = Firebase
      .firestore //access firestore
      .collection("blog") //access "blogs" collection
      .where("status", "==", true)
      .orderBy("createdAt")
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    //   .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        //You can "listen" to a document with the onSnapshot() method.
        const listBlogs =  querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          //map each document into snapshot
          id: doc.id, //id and data pushed into blogs array
          ...doc.data() //spread operator merges data to id.
        }));
        setBlogs(listBlogs); //blogs is equal to listBlogs
      });
    return 
    // () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
  return blogs;
};

const BlogList = ({ editBlog }) => {
  const listBlog = useBlogs();
  return (
    <div>
      {listBlog.map(blog => (
        <Card key={blog.id} hoverable={true} style={{marginTop: "20px", marginBottom: "20px"}}>

            <Title level={4} >{blog.title} </Title>
            <Tag color="geekblue" style={{ float: "right"}}>{blog.category} </Tag>
            <Paragraph><Text>{blog.caption}

            </Text></Paragraph> 
            <Link to={`/readblog/${blog.id}`}>Read</Link>
            <Link to={`/blog/${blog.id}`}>Read</Link>
        </Card>       
      ))}
      </div>
  );
};
export default BlogList;
```

Then I have a route defined with:

```
export const BLOGINDEX = '/blog';
export const BLOGPOST = '/blog/:id';
export const NEWBLOG = '/newblog';
export const EDITBLOG = '/editblog';
export const VIEWBLOG = '/viewblog';
export const READBLOG = '/readblog/:id';
```

I can't find a tutorial that does this with hooks. Can anyone see how to link from an index to a document that I can show in a different page?

I did find this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/TomBina/Simple-React-App/tree/building_custom_hooks_for_firebase?file=/src/UpdateCustomer.js). It looks like it is rendering a clean page in the updateCustomer page and using data from the index to do it - but the example is too clever for me to unpick without an explanation of what's happening (in particular, the updateCustomer file defines a setCustomer variable, by reference to useForm - but there is nothing in useForm with that definition. That variable is used in the key part of the file that tries to identify the data) - so I can't mimic the steps.

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

I found this [blog post](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/) which suggests some changes for locating the relevant document.

I implemented these changes and while I can print the correct document.id on the read page, I cannot find a way to access the document properties (eg: blog.title).

```
import React, { useHook } from 'react';
import {
    useParams
  } from 'react-router-dom';

import Firebase from "../../../firebase";
import BlogList from './View';


function ReadBlogPost() {
    let { slug } = useParams()
        // ...


    return (
        <div>{slug} 
        </div>
    )
};

export default ReadBlogPost;
```

**NEXT ATTEMPT:**

I tried to use the slug as the doc.id to get the post document as follows:

```
import React, { useHook, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    useParams
  } from 'react-router-dom';



import Firebase from "../../../firebase";
import BlogList from './View';


function ReadBlogPost() {
    let { slug } = useParams()
        // ...
    useEffect(() => {
        const blog = 
    Firebase.firestore.collection("blog").doc(slug);

            blog.get().then(function(doc) {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
doc.data();
                } else {
                    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                    console.log("No such document!");
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            });
        });


        return (
            <div>{blog.title} 
            </div>
        )
    };

    export default ReadBlogPost;
```

It returns an error saying blog is not defined. I also tried to return {doc.title} but I get the same error. I can see all the data in the console.

I really can't make sense of coding documentation - I can't figure out the starting point to decipher the instructions so most things I learn are by trial and error but I've run out of places to look for inspiration to try something new.

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

My next attempt is to try and follow the lead in this [tutorial](https://dev.to/bmcmahen/using-firebase-with-react-hooks-21ap).

```
function ReadBlogPost(blog) {
    let { slug } = useParams()
        // ...
    useEffect(() => {
        const blog = 
Firebase.firestore.collection("blog").doc(slug);

        blog.get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                doc.data()
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });

    },
    [blog]
);


    return (
        <div><Title level={4} > {blog.title}

        </Title>

        <p>{console.log(blog)}</p>


        </div>
    )
};

export default ReadBlogPost;
```

When I try this, the only odd thing is that the console.log inside the useEffect method gives all the data accurately, but when I log it form inside the return method, I get a load of gibberish (shown in the picture below).[image]

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

I found this [tutorial](https://dev.to/ashleemboyer/build-a-react-firebase-blog-site-part-3-4c5e), which uses realtime database instead of firestore, but I tried to copy the logic.

My read post page now has:

```
import React, { useHook, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    useParams
  } from 'react-router-dom';

import Firebase from "../../../firebase";
import BlogList from './View';
import { Card, Divider, Form, Icon, Input, Switch, Layout, Tabs, Typography, Tag, Button } from 'antd';
const { Paragraph, Text, Title } = Typography;


 const ReadBlogPost = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [currentPost, setCurrentPost] = useState();



    let { slug } = useParams()

    if (loading && !currentPost) {
        Firebase
          .firestore
          .collection("blog")
          .doc(slug)
          .get()
          .then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                setCurrentPost(...doc.data());
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            }
          }),  

          setLoading(false)
          }

          if (loading) {
            return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
          }





    return (
        <div><Title level={4} > 
        {currentPost.caption}
        {console.log({currentPost})}

        </Title>




        </div>
    )

};
export default ReadBlogPost;
```

Maybe this blog post is old, or maybe it's to do with it using .js where I have .jsx - which I think means I can't use [if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573277/react-expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw-an-expression), but I can't get this to work either. The error says:

> Line 21:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw
>   an expression  no-unused-expressions

It points to the line starting with Firebase.

I got rid of all the loading bits to try and make the data render. That gets rid of the above error message for now. However, I still can't return the values from currentPost.

It's really odd to me that inside the return statement, I cannot output {currentPost.title} - I get an error saying title is undefined, but when I try to output {currentPost} the error message says:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {caption, category, createdAt, post, status, title}). If you meant to
>   render a collection of children, use an array instead.

That makes no sense! I'd love to understand why I can log these values before the return statement, and inside the return statement, I can log them on the object but I cannot find how to log them as attributes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: is your `useBlog()` hook returning the expected data? If so, all you need to do is define your `<Link/>` components correctly.

```js
<Link 
  // This will look like /readblog/3. Curly braces mean
  // that this prop contains javascript that needs to be
  // evaluated, thus allowing you to create dynamic urls.
  to={`/readblog/${blog.id}`}
  // Make sure to open in a new window
  target="_blank"
>
  Read
</Link>
```

Edit: If you want to pass the data to the new component you need to set up a store in order to avoid fetching the same resource twice (once when mounting the list and once when mounting the BlogPost itself)

```js
// Define a context
const BlogListContext = React.createContext()

// In a top level component (eg. App.js) define a provider
const App = () => {
  const [blogList, setBlogList] = useState([])

  return (
    <BlogListContext.Provider value={{blogList, setBlogList}}>
      <SomeOtherComponent/>
    </BlogListContext.Provider>
  )
}

// In your BlogList component
const BlogList = ({ editBlog }) => {
  const { setBlogList } = useContext(BlogListContext)
  const listBlog = useBlogs()

  // Update the blog list from the context each time the
  // listBlog changes
  useEffect(() => {
    setBlogList(listBlog)
  }, [listBlog])
  return (
    // your components and links here
  )
}

// In your ReadBlog component
const ReadBlogComponent = ({ match }) => {
  const { blogList } = useContext(BlogListContext)
  // Find the blog by the id from params.
  const blog = blogList.find(blog => blog.id === match.params.id) || {}

  return (
    // Your JSX
  )
}
```

There are other options for passing data as well:

1. Through url params (not recommended).
2. Just pass the ID and let the component fetch its own data on mount.

Comment: It works to render a page with a url that has the right doc id in it, but I can't find a way to then use the document data in the readblog page to display the data. I don't know how to be able to do: blog.title in that page etc.

Comment: Oh, it wasn't clear to me what was your problem. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try to work through this. Do you have any suggestions for where I could learn more about the 2nd of your alternative options?

Comment: You are already passing the blog id as a url param (React Navigation does this for you). All you need to do is to get the ID from the `match.params` object (docs here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) and then use an useEffect hook to call the firebase api on mount passing the ID.

Comment: This is what I am trying to figure out how to do. I've just tried the context solution you provided above - I must be missing something because I can't get it to recognise the provider. Maybe I can try this match.params solution to work through this problem instead. Do you know where I can find an example of the useEffect solution?

Comment: I found this blog: https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/. I'll try to follow it's ideas. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that works for each attribute other than the timestamp.

```
const [currentPost, setCurrentPost] = useState([]);
```

There is an empty array in the useState() initialised state.

In relation to the timestamps - I've been through this hell so many times with firestore timestamps - most recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277859/react-display-a-firestore-timestamp). The solution that worked in December 2019 no longer works. Back to tearing my hair out over that one...