# How to fetch data don't use useEffect variable in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs.I don't know how fetch data using useEffect.When i use javascrift it's very easy to use. I have been struggling with adding data fetched from Firestore through useEffect and getDocs() into an useState variable. I wanna fetch all quizzes from ...

Comment: This may help you get better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

In the meantime I'd look at https://react-query.tanstack.com/ or https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview - useEffect is relatively low-level.

Comment: Check this:
[React useEffect to get firestore data once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178920/react-useeffect-to-get-firestore-data-once)