# React: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "("

Tags: reactjs

i am getting `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "("`.

I have no idea where i'm getting this unexpected error. anyways i'm probably new to reactJS. It would be great if anybody could figure out where i'm getting this unexpected error. thank you so much in advance.

[image]

./src/components/listing/Search.js :

```
function PostListPageByUser() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState([]);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    function handleChange(event) {
        setUserId(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleClick = (event) => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/car/p_list?search=" + event, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <section class="product_list section_padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="product_sidebar">
                        <div class="single_sedebar">
                            <form>
                                <input type="text" name="search" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Search keyword"/>
                                <i class="ti-search" onClick={handleClick}></i>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="product_list">
                        <div class="row"> <br/><br/><br/>

                        {
                            posts.map((post) => {<ul key={post.id}>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-9">

                                    <img src={post.product_image} alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                                    <h3>{post.title}</h3>

                                </div>
                            </ul>})
                        }

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues with your snippet.

Firstly, since you are using an arrow function for `handleClick`, you need to change it to:

```
    const handleClick = (event) => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/car/p_list?search=" + event, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
        .then(res => {
            const posts = res.data;
            setPost(posts);
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Secondly,

```
{
    posts.map((post) => {
        return(
            <ul key={post.id}>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
                <img src={post.product_image} alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                </div>
            </ul>
        )
    })
}
```

As an aside, the `ul` tag is misused here. You should use a `div` instead. That should not stop your code from working though but for the sake of knowledge and working in a production environment, it's important you always use the right tags. You can learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this part

```js
const handleClick = (event) => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/car/p_list?search=" + event, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

you cannot use the `function` and `arrow function` syntax simultaneously!

Comment: okay! now i'm getting this error: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`

Comment: please read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573277/react-expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw-an-expression

Comment: i didn't get any useful from this above link.